# Unzip an array of tuples in julia

Tags: julia

Suppose I have an array of tuples:

```
arr = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
```

With python I can do `zip(*arr) == [(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)]`

What is the equivalent of this in julia?

Comment: rather `zip(arr...) |> collect`: need to splat `arr` within `zip`, like in the "proof of correctness".

Comment: @amrods is right. Those pesky splat `...` slipped away at top of first comment. For correctness' sake, will re-comment the comment.

Comment: `zip(arr...) |> collect` should do it. And one should ponder the following at least once: `collect(zip(zip(arr...)...)) == arr` which is true generally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**For larger arrays use @ivirshup's solution below.**

For smaller arrays, you can use `zip` and splitting.

You can achieve the same thing in Julia by using the `zip()` function [(docs here)](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/iterators/#Base.Iterators.zip). `zip()` expects many tuples to work with so you have to use the [splatting operator](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/faq/) `...` to supply your arguments. Also in Julia you have to use the `collect()` function to then transform your iterables into an array (if you want to).

Here are these functions in action:

```
arr = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]

# wtihout splatting
collect(zip((1,2), (3,4), (5,6)))

# Output is a vector of arrays:
> ((1,3,5), (2,4,6))

# same results with splatting
collect(zip(arr...))
> ((1,3,5), (2,4,6))
```

Comment: Note that for large arrays this is very slow! See https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/13930#issuecomment-155142306

Comment: For arrays as small as 1000 elements this will cause a stack overflow and _crash_ Julia. So like .. don't use this, unless you know that the size of arr will never go above, say, 50.

Answer (score 11):

As an alternative to splatting (since that's pretty slow), you could do something like:

```
unzip(a) = map(x->getfield.(a, x), fieldnames(eltype(a)))
```

This is pretty quick.

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools
julia> a = collect(zip(1:10000, 10000:-1:1));
julia> @benchmark unzip(a)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  156.45 KiB
  allocs estimate:  6
  --------------
  minimum time:     25.260 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      31.997 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        48.429 μs (25.03% GC)
  maximum time:     36.130 ms (98.67% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     1
```

By comparison, I have yet to see this complete:

```
@time collect(zip(a...))
```

Comment: I can confirm that the `unzip` function in this answer is more than 10x faster than splatting into `zip` and also uses much less memory. I'm using a Mac running Julia 1.1.

Comment: To unzip an array of arrays of equal length, `unzip(a) = [getindex.(a, i) for i in 1:length(a[1])]` works pretty well

Answer (score 2):

julia:

use ...

```
for r in zip(arr...)
println(r)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also the [Unzip.jl](https://github.com/bramtayl/Unzip.jl) package:

```
julia> using Unzip

julia> unzip([(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)])
([1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6])
```

which seems to work a bit faster than the selected answer:

```
julia> using Unzip, BenchmarkTools

julia> a = collect(zip(1:10000, 10000:-1:1));

julia> unzip_ivirshup(a) = map(x->getfield.(a, x), fieldnames(eltype(a))) ;

julia> @btime unzip_ivirshup($a);
  18.439 μs (4 allocations: 156.41 KiB)

julia> @btime unzip($a); # unzip from Unzip.jl is faster
  12.798 μs (4 allocations: 156.41 KiB)

julia> unzip(a) == unzip_ivirshup(a) # check output is the same
true
```

Answer (score 2):

I will add a solution based on the following simple macro

```
"""
    @unzip xs, ys, ... = us

will expand the assignment into the following code
    xs, ys, ... = map(x -> x[1], us), map(x -> x[2], us), ...
"""
macro unzip(args)
    args.head != :(=) && error("Expression needs to be of form `xs, ys, ... = us`")
    lhs, rhs = args.args
    items = isa(lhs, Symbol) ? [lhs] : lhs.args
    rhs_items = [:(map(x -> x[$i], $rhs)) for i in 1:length(items)]
    rhs_expand = Expr(:tuple, rhs_items...)
    esc(Expr(:(=), lhs, rhs_expand))
end
```

Since it's just a syntactic expansion, there shouldn't be any performance or type instability issue. Compare to other solutions based on `fieldnames`, this has the advantage of also working when the array element type is abstract. For example, while

```
julia> unzip_get_field(a) = map(x->getfield.(a, x), fieldnames(eltype(a)));
julia> unzip_get_field(Any[("a", 3), ("b", 4)])
ERROR: ArgumentError: type does not have a definite number of fields
```

the macro version still works:

```
julia> @unzip xs, ys = Any[("a", 3), ("b",4)]
(["a", "b"], [3, 4])
```

Answer (score 1):

Following up on @ivirshup 's answer I would like to add a version that is still an iterator

```
unzip(a) = (getfield.(a, x) for x in fieldnames(eltype(a)))
```

which keeps the result unevaluated until used. It even gives a (very slight) speed improvement when comparing

```
@benchmark a1, b1 = unzip(a)
```

```
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  156.52 KiB
  allocs estimate:  8
  --------------
  minimum time:     33.185 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      76.581 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        83.808 μs (18.35% GC)
  maximum time:     7.679 ms (97.82% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     1
```

vs.

```
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  156.52 KiB
  allocs estimate:  8
  --------------
  minimum time:     33.914 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      39.020 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        64.788 μs (16.52% GC)
  maximum time:     7.853 ms (98.18% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a minimal package intended to simplify the broadcast-unzip use case: [UnzipLoops.jl](https://github.com/Suzhou-Tongyuan/UnzipLoops.jl).

Instead of writing this explicitly:

```
out = f.(X, Y)
function g(X, Y)
    out = f.(X, Y)
    return map(x->x[1], out), map(x->x[2], out)
end
```

the package provides this as an efficient shorthand:

```
@assert g(X, Y) == broadcast_unzip(f, X, Y)
```

See the UnzipLoops.jl package documentation for more details and alternatives. Relative to [Unzip.jl](https://github.com/bramtayl/Unzip.jl), I think this package is more recent, has a more restricted API, and aims for more performance?

There is also a long-standing issue on the Julia repo about adding a `Base.unzip()`: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/13942.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the macro of @MrVPlusOne, here is a variant that is type-strict:

```
@generated function unzip(a::A) where {T <: Tuple, A <: AbstractArray{T}}
    isconcretetype(T) || error("Tuple types vary")
    N = length(T.parameters)
    ith_subarray(a, i) = map(x -> x[i], a)
    elems = [Expr(:call, ith_subarray, :a, i) for i in 1:N]
    return Expr(:tuple, elems...)
end
```

Use it like this:

```
@assert unzip([(1,"A"),(2,"B")]) == ([1,2], ["A","B"])
unzip([(1,"A"),(2,3)]) # Error: Tuple types vary
unzip([(1,2),(3,)])    # Error: Tuple types vary
```