# Julia: how to optimally declare a vector containing interpolations?

Tags: function, types, julia, interpolation, declaration

I'm an economics student slowly switching from MATLAB to Julia.

Currently, my problem is that I don't know how to declare (preallocate) a vector that could store interpolations.

Specifically, when I execute something close to:

```
function MyFunction(i)
    # x, y vectors are some functions of 'i' defined here 
    f = LinearInterpolation(x,y,extrapolation_bc=Line())
    return f
end    

g = Vector{Function}(undef, N)
    
for i = 1:N
    g[i] = MyFunction(i)
end
```

I get:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Interpolations.Extrapolation{Float64,1,Interpolations.GriddedInterpolation{Float64,1,Float64,Gridded{Linear},Tuple{Array{Float64,1}}},Gridded{Linear},Line{Nothing}} to an object of type Function
```

If I, instead of `g=Vector{Function}(undef, N)`, declare `g=zeros(N)`, I get a similar error message (ending with with `...Float64` rather than with `... Function`).

When I, instead, declare:

```
g = Interpolations.Extrapolation{Float64,1,Interpolations.GriddedInterpolation{Float64,1,Float64,Gridded{Linear},Tuple{Array{Float64,1}}},Gridded{Linear},Line{Nothing}}(N)
```

I get:

```
LoadError: MethodError: no method matching Interpolations.Extrapolation{Float64,1,Interpolations.GriddedInterpolation{Float64,1,Float64,Gridded{Linear},Tuple{Array{Float64,1}}},Gridded{Linear},Line{Nothing}}(::Int64) Closest candidates are: Interpolations.Extrapolation{Float64,1,Interpolations.GriddedInterpolation{Float64,1,Float64,Gridded{Linear},Tuple{Array{Float64,1}}},Gridded{Linear},Line{Nothing}}(::Any, !Matched::Any) where {T, N, ITPT, IT, ET}
```

When I don't declare "g" at all, then I get:

```
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: g not defined
```

Finally, when I declare:

```
g = Vector{Any}(undef, N)
```

the code works, though I'm afraid this might induce some type-change of a variable `g`, thereby slowing down my performance-sensitive code.

How, ideally then, should I declare `g` in this case?

**EDIT:**
In reality, my problem is a bit more complex, more like the following:

```
function MyFunction(i)
# x, y vectors are some functions of 'i' defined here        
f = LinearInterpolation(x,y,extrapolation_bc=Line())
h = is a T-vector of some functions of x,y
A = is some matrix depending on x,y
    return h, A, f
end
 
h = Matrix{Function}(undef, T, N)
A = zeros(T,I,N)
g = Vector{Any}(undef, N)

for i = 1:N
    h[:,i], A[:,:,i], g[i] = MyFunction(i)
end
```

So, when I use either comprehension or broadcasting (like `h, A, g = [MyFunction(i) for i in 1:N]` or `h, A, g = MyFunction.(1:N)`), as users Benoit and DNS suggested below, the outputs of my function are 3 tuples, h, A, g, each containing {h[i], A[i], g[i]} for i=1,2,3. If I use only 1 output variable on the LHS, instead, i.e.: `MyOutput = [MyFunction(i) for i in 1:N]` or `MyOutput[i] = MyFunction.(1:N)`, then `MyOutput` becomes a vector with N tuple entries, every tuple consisting of {h[i], A[i], g[i]} i=1,2,3,...,N. I bet there's a way of extracting these elements from the tuples in `MyOutput` and filling them inside `h[:,i], A[:,:,i], g[i]`, but that seems a bit cumbersome and slow.

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```
f = MyFunction(1)
g = Vector{typeof(f)}(undef, N)
g[1] = f
    
for i = 2:N
    g[i] = MyFunction(i)
end
```

I think also `map` should figure out the type:

```
map(MyFunction, 1:N)
```

Comment: Many thanks! I didn't think of these solutions.

I tried the first, but it is a bit slower even than the one using 'Vector{Any}(undef, N)'.

I tried the second, but for some weird reason it only gives me an error message "MethodError: no method matching LinearInterpolation(::Float64, ::Float64; extrapolation_bc=Line())"

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is to use a [comprehension](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#man-comprehensions):

```
g = [MyFunction(i) for i in 1:N]
```

or elegantly use the [dot syntax](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#man-vectorized):

```
g = MyFunction.(1:N)
```

(Credit to DNF for the dot-syntax solution suggested in the comments.)

Comment: Or even just `g = MyFunction.(1:N)`

Comment: Thanks for the intput, guys! I addressed these solutions in the edit of my original post. Please, look at it.

Comment: I think your edit is a different question. You're now asking how to turn a vector of tuples into a tuple of vectors. I'm not sure I understand why you'd need that though. Say you have the vector of tuples `hAfs = MyFunction.(1:N)`. You can instead now loop through that as in `h, A, f = hAfs[i]` for whatever computation you have, no?

Comment: The problem is now more complex, but the my basic question of how to solve it quickly is still relevant. In particular, with your suggestion of `hAfs = MyFunction.(1:N)` and for-looping over `h[:,i], A[:,:,i], g[i] = hAfs[i]`, still the `g` needs to be declared beforehand, and the problem boils down to preallocating it more reasonably than with `g = Vector{Any}(undef, N)`, right?

Comment: I don't think so. Once all your tuples are created inside `hAfs`, you can just access them directly. That is, no need to reallocate a vector of vectors, a vector of matrices, and a vector of interpolants. E.g., if you need the 2nd interpolant `f` you can get it via `_, _, f = hAfs[2]`.

Comment: FWIW, for your second question, there is [Unzip.jl](https://github.com/bramtayl/Unzip.jl), for which you could simply do `hs, As, fs = unzip(hAfs)`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check these!

Comment: @BenoitPasquier, I really don't know how to use the link you provided. The function `unzip()` in `As, fs = unzip(hAfs)` doesn't work for me (I get `UndefVarError: unzip not defined`), when I install `unzip.jl` with import `Pkg; Pkg.add("unzip")`, then I get `he following package names could not be resolved:
 * unzip (not found in project, manifest or registry)`, and finally, I don't know how to make use of the link you provided. Can you help?

Comment: The "U" in the package name, "Unzip", should be in uppercase. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67394001/5602149 for an example use (and also some other one-liner function solutions already there).

Comment: Thanks! It works for me when I, say, declare a matrix of 2-element tuples and want to create 2 matrices out of it. However, I have problems with more real-work examples, e.g. for this code:
`MyFunction(x,y) = x+y, x*y
myOutputs = Array{Any}(undef,3,2)
for (i,N) = enumerate([10 20 30])
    for (j,C) = enumerate([0.1 0.2])
        myOutputs[i,j] = @timed MyFunction(N,C)
    end 
end
sum1, sum2, times = unzip(myOutputs)` I get `BoundsError: attempt to access 0-element Unzip.Rows{Tuple{}, 1, Tuple{}} at index [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.

Comment: Even without `@timed` and with `sum1, sum2 = unzip(myOutputs)`, I do get exactly the same error. How can I fix that?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe start a new question with that MWE and the desired output?

Comment: Maybe try `myOutputs = [@timed MyFunction(N,C) for N in [10, 20, 30], C in [0.1, 0.2]]` and then `sums, times = unzip(myOutputs)`.

Comment: The issue being that your `myOutput` was of element type `Any` and `unzip` needs to know the element type (here a `NamedTuple`) in order to fetch the entries of the elements.